# Navigation is only pushing text in the first 100% on website

Tags: html, css

I have a little Problem.

I made this Sidebar Navigation (I also added like a million "hey's" to show the problem):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

nav {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 250px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  float: left;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

nav ul li i {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

nav ul li .arrow {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  background: #F2F2F2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 


<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><i class="bi bi-house-door"></i> Home</li>
    <li><i class="bi bi-envelope"></i> Messages</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p>
```

When you see the page then you will notice that the naviagation is on the left and the text on the right but after the first 100% of the page height the text is moving to the left like this (Also press full page in the snippet):

[image]

How could I fix this problem? Ask me in the comments if you didn't understand something

Thanks in advance and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

**CSS Solution**

```
p { margin-left: 250px; }
```

Just suggestion to put the rest of your HTML body content in div and give that div margin-left the same size as nav width so it will not make a problem for you.

Comment: Hi @kamran, thanks for your answer! Unfortunately i will resize the Navigation sometimes and that means that this isn't compact. Is there another way to achieve this WITHOUT a margin-left?

Comment: In that case, you will need to use javascript to add margin same as sidebar since you want to push content against sidenav you have to margin-left the same size of sidenav to parent div of the body content.
this example might help you to understand 
https://codepen.io/govindjha/pen/MKrYVL

Answer (score 0):

Put your `p` in  a container and apply `margin-left` equal to the width of `nav` ,i.e, here it is `250px` (This way it will be applied to specific tags only not on all)

```
.container {
  margin-left: 250px
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

nav {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 250px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

nav ul li i {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

nav ul li .arrow {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  background: #F2F2F2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  margin-left: 250px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><i class="bi bi-house-door"></i> Home</li>
    <li><i class="bi bi-envelope"></i> Messages</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Rana, thanks for your answer! Unfortunately i will resize the Navigation sometimes and that means that this isn't compact. Is there another way to achieve this **WITHOUT** a margin-left?

Comment: Resize in the sense you will change width of `nav` or other thing like different screen sizes have different width

Comment: Yes, for example when using another language or the responsive Version. But i will definetely change something later

Comment: Then as in answer above `margin-left` value will be equal to width of `nav` . If you change width of `nav` than change `margin-left` value to same

Comment: @JustChillinInDaHood you can use css variables for control width and margin together. You don't need to use sticky position if you want fix navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all the `<p>` tags in a single `<div>` (lets call it "container") like this:

```
 <div class='container'>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
 </div>`
```

then add the following properties in the css file

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

nav {
  height: 200vh;
  width: 250px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  float: left;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

nav ul li i {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

nav ul li .arrow {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  background: #F2F2F2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><i class="bi bi-house-door"></i> Home</li>
    <li><i class="bi bi-envelope"></i> Messages</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p>

<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    const height = document.body.scrollHeight;
    document.querySelector("nav").style.height = `${height}px`;
});
</script>
```

The snippet above computes the actual height of the page and applies it.